# resize image in table cell in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

When I put my image into my table cell, it always fill the cell. Even though I set the image size with different values. Here's my code:

```
    ...
    myTable.row();
    Image imageActor = new Image(skin.getDrawable("bowArrowSq3"));
    imageActor.setSize(300, 100);
    myTable.add(imageActor).width(300).height(200)
            .pad(padding);
    myTable.row();
    ....
```

In the above code, imageActor's  height is always 200 as set by parent cell. How do I size my image and place it somewhere in my cell?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a container:

```
myTable.row();
Image imageActor = new Image(skin.getDrawable("bowArrowSq3"));
imageActor.setSize(300, 100);
Table container = new Table();
container.addActor(imageActor);
myTable.add(container).width(300).height(200).pad(padding);
myTable.row();
```

Container will fit the cell but you should be able to place the image where you want within it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (size of actor needs to be same as cell), the problem was the image was scaled (default). After setting scale type it worked as expected.

`imageActor.setScaling(Scaling.fit);
myTable.add(imageActor).width(300).height(200).pad(padding); //image is not streched`